# Set a string when a CheckBox has been checked (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a check box in WinForms, when checked I would like it to set a string e.g.:

```
string CheckBox = true
```

**Edit:** Or would this be a better example:

```
bool checkbox = true;
```

So when a method is run it will lookup the string and dependent on it's value with perform a a submethod...

So the question is really how do you set a string on a CheckBox when it is clicked, I have checked the Actions list and the closest is "CheckChanged", but obviously it won't work.

Comment: Why cant you use CheckChanged? It is a function that is performed when a user clicks the checkbox. You can do whatever you want in there.

Comment: Why CheckChanged doesn't work?

Comment: jmein: Because how can you tell whether it has been checked or unchecked? I assume it could get quite confusing..? - If its not checked the string should return "false"

Comment: @Adam Jones Just check the .Checked value of the checkbox like Shoaib did in his answer

Comment: `(sender as CheckBox).Checked` -- or something to that effect...

Comment: Why do people use SO instead of google for things like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would CheckChanged not work?

```
bool checkbox = false;
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

   if (CheckBox1.Checked)
   {
      checkbox = true;
   }
}
```

Or just use `CheckBox1.Checked` in your subroutine.

Comment: Thank you, that has clarified it! :)

Comment: @Adam, where he has the line `checkbox = true` above, just put your "submethod" code. You do not need to hold the value of the checkbox now that you realize it can be retrieved at any time...

Answer (score 0):

First off, `string checkbox` is not a boolean value. It is a string!

A list of CheckBox events is listed here at MSDN. You should utilize [CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox_events.aspx) or [CheckStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox_events.aspx). When the check box state changes, you can set a boolean value or modify a string based on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
string someString = String.Empty;


...


private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    someString = CheckBox1.Checked.ToString();
}
```

Then `someString` will be "true" or "false"

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
string chk;

Public oncheckboxcheckchangedevent()
{
    if(checkbox1.checked)
    {
        chk="somevalue";
    }
}
```